# MYSQL connection through ssh with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have two hosts: my laptop and an MYSQL server to which I need to connect to.

The only access to the server is via ssh (with public key authentication). From there I can connect to mysql and send queries.

How can I do this in ruby? I can connect to my host like this

```
Net::SSH.start(ssh_host, ssh_user, :port => ssh_port, :keys => keys, :passphrase => passphrase) do |ssh|
  result = ssh.exec!('ls')
  puts result
end
```

But I dont know how to proceed from here on :(
Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with ruby (as opposed to setting up an ssh tunnel) ?

Comment: This might be of use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404214/cannot-connect-to-remote-db-using-ssh-tunnel-and-activerecord/5282259#5282259

Comment: do you have ruby and mysql2 gem installed on your remote server? If not is it possible for you to install that?